# Получить email через VK SDK PHP

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте, php-vksdk

Пишу авторизацию на php через vk. Первое, что делаю:

```
$oauth = new VKOAuth();
    $client_id = 00000000;
    $redirect_uri = 'https://site.com/vk-step-2';
    $display = VKOAuthDisplay::PAGE;
    $scope = array(VKOAuthUserScope::WALL, VKOAuthUserScope::GROUPS, VKOAuthUserScope::EMAIL);
    $state = 'secret_state_code';
    $browser_url = $oauth->getAuthorizeUrl(VKOAuthResponseType::CODE, $client_id, $redirect_uri, $display, $scope, $state);
    return $this->redirect($browser_url);
```

Тут все проходит хорошо, у пользователя запрашивает доступ и дальше такой код:

```
$oauth = new VKOAuth();
    $client_id = 0000000;
    $client_secret = '567890шгнрголд';
    $redirect_uri = 'https://site.com/vk-step-2';
    $code = $_GET['code'];

    $response = $oauth->getAccessToken($client_id, $client_secret, $redirect_uri, $code);
    $access_token = $response['access_token'];

    $vk = new VKApiClient();
    $response = $vk->users()->get($access_token, array(
        'fields' => array('photo', 'email'),
    ));
    return $response;
```

Данные я получаю, но не получаю email. Хотя при запросе доступа есть пункт о email. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Только те компании, которые заплатили приличные деньги за то, что-бы получать email не задаются таким вопросом.

Comment: то есть, проще говоря, такой возможности нету?

Comment: Сложилось впечатление что предоставление комфортных условий для начинающих девелоперов (имею ввиду без мешка денег) не в приоритете у ВК. Взял в закладку Ваш вопрос. Если вдруг кто-то, как-то найдет способ и напишет ответ - я с удовольствием им воспользуюсь.

Answer (score 2):

```
$response = $vk->users()->get($access_token, array(
    'user_ids' => $user_id,
    'fields' => array('photo', 'email'),
));
```

$user_id - ID пользователя у которого нужно получить Email.
У меня так работало раньше, но теперь не стал получать Email, не все одобряют.

$user_id можно взять после получения $response, если это один и тот же пользователь.

```
$response = $oauth->getAccessToken($client_id, $client_secret, $redirect_uri, $code);
$access_token = $response['access_token'];
$user_id = $response['user_id'];
```